# How to get sum with different description in column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
id| name    total
1 |      meow    1
2 |      meow    2
3 |      raf     5
4 |      meow    5
5 |      raf     5
```

i want a result with this

meow  =8
raf =10

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Put some effort into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT name,
         SUM(total) total_sum
    FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: @bluefeet: oh, called the column `total_sum` and wrote `COUNT()`. That's weird

Comment: @bluefeet: double fault, shame on me :-(

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply it really help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a group of the names to get individual sums

```
select name, sum(total) as totals
from your_table
group by name
```